# django-ckeditor doesn't show up on grappelli admin in Django

Tags: django, ckeditor

I'm trying to use ckeditor on grappelli admin in Django. In local environment, it's working very well and it shows up well. However, after deploying it into production environment. The editor doesn't show up.

Like you see image below, it's just blank and nothing.

[image]

**settings.py**

```
DJANGO_APPS = [
    ...
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader'
]

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "ckeditor_uploads/"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': [["Format", "Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "SpellChecker"],
                    ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', "Indent", "Outdent", 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter',
                     'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
                    ["Image", "Table", "Link", "Unlink", "Anchor", "SectionLink",
                        "Subscript", "Superscript"], ['Undo', 'Redo'], ["Source"],
                    ["Maximize"]],
    },
}

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

These are all settings for ckeditor in my Django app.
Does anyone know why it's happening?